# What is wrong with this cumulative sum function, and is there a better way to write the function?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, arraylist

Function:

```
def comulative_sum(arr):
    arr1 = []
    for number in range(1, len(arr)):
        sum1 = 0
        for number1 in range(0, arr[number]):
            sum1 += number1
        arr1.append(sum1)
    return arr1
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(comulative_sum(arr))
```

Output:

```
[3, 6, 10]
```

Expected output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

I have tried slicing ([1:], [0:number) instead of the range function. Still no results.

Comment: Is the expected output correct for cumulative sum? Shouldn't it be like 1 4 10 20 or am I misinterpreting it

Comment: Well yes but I accidently copied the ouput into both input and output. My bad.

Comment: Does your IDE print out results if you don't tell it to print it?  Have you tried `print(comulative_sum(arr))`.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to write this function is simply using [`itertools.accumulate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) which does exactly that:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> print(list(itertools.accumulate([1,2,3,4]))
[1, 3, 6, 10]
```

Comment: this is really the right answer in a non academic setting +1

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

- On the first loop you need to range until `len() + 1` as the last number is `len()` and then the last number in second loop will be `len() - 1` which is also the index.
- On the second loop, instead of ranging until `number`, you range until the original number in the array.

Fixed code:

```
def comulative_sum(arr):
    arr1 = []
    for number in range(1, len(arr)+1):
        sum1 = 0
        for number1 in range(0, number):
            sum1 += arr[number1]
        arr1.append(sum1)
    return arr1
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(comulative_sum(arr))
```

---

If you wish to improve upon this code and not use a built-in accumulate, you can do so:

```
def comulative_sum(input_list):
    output = []
    sum_ = 0  # The underscore is to avoid renaming the built-in sum()
    for i in input_list:
        sum_ += i
        output.append(sum_)
    return output

input_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(comulative_sum(input_list))
```

Advantages:

1. Better variable naming.
2. Less code nesting.
3. Easier overall code readability.
4. Faster code (no need to recalculate everything on each iteration)

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will only deal with numbers from index 1 to the end of the array. Thus index 0 will be ignored.

Working function:

```
def comulative_sum(arr):
arr1 = []
for number in arr[:len(arr)]:
    sum1 = 0
    for number1 in arr[0:number]:
        sum1 += number1
    arr1.append(sum1)
return arr1
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(comulative_sum(arr))
```

All that was changed was the indexing in the first and second for loop.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to loop it twice

```
def cum_sum(x):
    result = []
    current_sum = 0
    for value in x:
        current_sum += value
        result.append(current_sum)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I built in your solution. This version relies on Python's loop through indexes and also addresses a possible number '0'.

```
def cumulative_sum(arr):
    arr1 = []
    # Python does the hard work for you, it loops through each value on the list
    for value in arr:
        sum1 = 0
        # Range is going to have a list as follows [0, ... , value-1]
        for number1 in range(0, value):
            sum1 += number1
        # Adding 'value' to sum1 because the loop did not add the last value
        arr1.append(sum1+value)
    return arr1

arr = [1, 3, 6, 10]
# Calling the function with 'print' to make sure the results are displayed
print(cumulative_sum(arr))
```